# Parsing a byte string with pyparsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

I have data packets coming from a network and I thought of using `pyparsing` to detect messages and extract specific data within the different packet types. Of course what is coming from the network is in the shape of a byte string such the following example.

```py
b'\x03\xff*******************************************************************'
```

where `*` represents any characters. Note that there is no specific encoding used such as `Unicode`.

I can use `pyparsing` with byte strings, it seems to work fine when I specify explicitly what to find such as:

```py
expr = Suppress(b'\x03\xff')
```

Now I want it find a sequence of 20 bytes for example placed after `Suppress(b'\x03\xff')`, and they can be anything. I thought of using an expression like `Regex('.{20}')` if the DOTALL flag could be used but I get anyhow the error:
`TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`

So how can I detect this sequence of 20 bytes of any kind ?

## Addendum

Trying @FMc proposal:

```py
from pyparsing import *
expr = Suppress(b'\x03\xff') + Regex(b'.{20}')
line = b'\x03\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff--4353425352FGDSGSFDGBFSDBGfdeGRES'
print(expr.parseString(line, parseAll=False).dump())
```

gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
  File "lib\site-packages\pyparsing\core.py", line 2384, in __init__
    self.mayReturnEmpty = self.re_match("") is not None
TypeError: cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object
```

Comment: If you are working with bytes, you need to do it across the board: `Regex(b'.{20}')`

Comment: I get the same error `TypeError: cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object`, so could you elaborate your example please?

Comment: I believe you that the error occurs, but it's hard to provide specific help without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need to be able to run the example, see the line the error occurs on, etc. Right now, everything is vague, and the only problem I see in your question text is that you were calling `Regex()` with a unicode string rather than bytes string. Maybe there are similar problems in the rest of your code?

Comment: when I try this with Python 3.8 then it gives me error even for bytes in `Suppress(b'\x03\xff')` - it seems it wants to work only with strings which means it needs to decode it.

Comment: and I am using `pyparsing==3.0.0a2`, but indeed version 2.4.7 reacts differently. I guess I need to use something else to parse

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the sake of testing before doing I tried Anthony Sottile's idea with the complete byte spectrum in the line to test and I get the following error:

```py
from pyparsing import *
expr = Suppress('\x03\xff') + Regex('.{20}')
line = b'\x03\xff\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2b\x2c\x2d\x2e\x2f\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x3a\x3b\x3c\x3d\x3e\x3f\x40\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4a\x4b\x4c\x4d\x4e\x4f\x50\x51\x52\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5a\x5b\x5c\x5d\x5e\x5f\x60\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69\x6a\x6b\x6c\x6d\x6e\x6f\x70\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7a\x7b\x7c\x7d\x7e\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
for tok in expr.parseString(line.decode('latin-1'), parseAll=False):
    print(tok.encode('latin-1'))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 4, in <module>
  File "\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1955, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 3342, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected Re:('.{20}'), found '\x00'  (at char 2), (line:1, col:3)
```

To make it work, I need the following:

```py
from pyparsing import *
import re
expr = Suppress('\x03\xff') + Regex(re.compile(r'.{256}', re.DOTALL))
line = b'\x03\xff\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2b\x2c\x2d\x2e\x2f\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x3a\x3b\x3c\x3d\x3e\x3f\x40\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4a\x4b\x4c\x4d\x4e\x4f\x50\x51\x52\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5a\x5b\x5c\x5d\x5e\x5f\x60\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69\x6a\x6b\x6c\x6d\x6e\x6f\x70\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7a\x7b\x7c\x7d\x7e\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
for tok in expr.parseString(line.decode('latin-1'), parseAll=False):
    print(tok.encode('latin-1'))
    print(len(tok), len(tok.encode('latin-1')))
```

output:

```py
b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08     \n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb'
256 256
```

However the printed string ends at `\xfb` and I wondered why since the length is well at 256. And it looks like the `TAB=\x09` is converted to 5 spaces so the conversion stops 4 characters before the \xff.
I discovered that the `parseString` converts the `TAB` to spaces. So by adding `parseWithTabs()` all works well:

```py
from pyparsing import *                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
import re                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
expr = Suppress('\x03\xff') + Regex(re.compile(r'.{256}', re.DOTALL))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
line = b'\x03\xff\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2b\x2c\x2d\x2e\x2f\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x3a\x3b\x3c\x3d\x3e\x3f\x40\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4a\x4b\x4c\x4d\x4e\x4f\x50\x51\x52\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5a\x5b\x5c\x5d\x5e\x5f\x60\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69\x6a\x6b\x6c\x6d\x6e\x6f\x70\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7a\x7b\x7c\x7d\x7e\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'    
expr.parseWithTabs()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
for tok in expr.parseString(line.decode('latin-1'), parseAll=False):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    print(tok.encode('latin-1'))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    print(len(tok), len(tok.encode('latin-1')))
```

output:

```py
b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
256 256
```

## Addendum

Actually to make sure it is going to work in every case, the default whitespace characters need to be updated so that they not skipped in some cases. In this case I chose to use `setDefaultWhitespaceChars()`

```py
ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars("")
```

Comment: use `re.DOTALL` to make `.` match the null byte

Answer (score 2):

It appears `pyparsing` only works on text (`str`) and not `bytes`.

One idea would be to convert the bytes to """text""" using `latin-1` (the trivial encoding) and then parse as text using that:

```py
from pyparsing import *
expr = Suppress('\x03\xff') + Regex('.{20}')
line = b'\x03\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff--4353425352FGDSGSFDGBFSDBGfdeGRES'
for tok in expr.parseString(line.decode('latin-1'), parseAll=False):
    print(tok.encode('latin-1'))
```

output:

```
$ python3 t.py 
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff--435342535'
```

Comment: Pyparsing was originally written under Python2, when bytes and strs mingled more easily. You may still get away with parsing bytes using pyparsing 2.4.7 with Python 2.7, but I feel better recommending the approach described in this answer. I had hoped to make pyparsing 3.0 able to accommodate parsing of bytes or strs, but as @FMc points out, there are many internal strs that would need baking out. For now, under Python3, this approach is probably the one most likely to allow you to progress most quickly.

Comment: Good Idea. I had to extend a bit to correct a few problems with it but that is a good base.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain, but I suspect that pyparsing is a **text parser**, not a bytes parser.  I see no mention of "binary" or "bytes" in the docs. The first paragraph in the [docs](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowToUsePyparsing.html#classes-in-the-pyparsing-module):

> This document provides how-to instructions for the pyparsing library,
> an easy-to-use Python module for constructing and executing basic text
> parsers.

When I added a `print([expr])` before the failing line in the pyparsing code base, a lot is printed giving me the impression that pyparsing has text-based assumptions baked into its code base. Here's a snippet of the output before it all blows up:

```
[<SP><TAB>]
[{{{~{","} ~{LineEnd}} W:(0123...)} [<SP><TAB>]}]
[{{{{~{","} ~{LineEnd}} W:(0123...)} [<SP><TAB>]}}...]
[{quotedString using single or double quotes | commaItem}]
[","]
[{Suppress:(",") [{quotedString using single or double quotes | commaItem}]}]
[b'\x03\xff']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 3, in <module>
    expr = Suppress(b'\x03\xff') + Regex(b'.{20}')
  File "/Users/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 5100, in __init__
    super(TokenConverter, self).__init__(expr)  # , savelist)
  File "/Users/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 4453, in __init__
    self.mayIndexError = expr.mayIndexError
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'mayIndexError'
```

Initially, I had an idea to use an encoding scheme (eg, hex) for parsing bytes
with pyparsing. But after some initial experiments I realized this path seems
complex -- and probably unworkable. The pyparsing library is deeply tied to
regex, both in its API and in its underlying implementation. For example, this
won't work as intended:

```
from pyparsing import Regex, ParseException

# Your input converted to hex.
line = b'\x03\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff--4353425352FGDSGSFDGBFSDBGfdeGRES'
hex_line = line.hex()

# An easy regex, naively converted to hex.
pattern = r'.{20}'
hex_pattern = pattern.encode().hex() # 2e7b32307d
rgx = Regex(hex_pattern)

# It doesn't work: the regex syntax has been lost. We end up searching for the
# literal 2e7b32307d, which isn't found.
try:
    print(rgx.parseString(hex_line, parseAll = False).dump())
except ParseException as e:
    print(e)

# A hex-minded regex for 20 arbitrary ACSII characters would be this:
hpattern = r'.{40}'
rgx = Regex(hpattern)

# This works.
print(rgx.parseString(hex_line, parseAll = False).dump())
```

But that example was too easy. Many regex concepts are less convenient to
represent in hex terms:

```
\d+            # Regex
(?:3[0-9])+    # Hex-centric regex? No thanks.
```

Unless your needs are simple (and, if so, why bother with pyparsing), this
path seems very hard. And again, don't forget that many of pyparsing's API
elements are implemented as normal regex under the hood.